# Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

When I create new mobile application in visual studio, I can run it and no problems happen.

But when I start running another application (created by other developer, and shared on TFS), I got the following messages:

```
Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple.

Unable to get Ripple session info for port 0.
```

No build errors or warnings! just 2 messages!!

Any idea?

My environment:

- Visual studio 2013 community edition (with Update 4)
- Windows 7, x64

*** EDIT:**

It worked by right-clicking project name in solution explorer | Debug | start new instance

But still didn't work by hitting F5 or clicking Run button in toolbar!!

Comment: No idea how to solve it. But I have a same setup - VS 2013.4 on Win 7 x64, - and a very similar problem `Unable to get Ripple session info for port 9223. A required web socket component is missing.` Just to let you know you are not alone :)

Comment: llia -- it seems WebSockett4Net is not installed which is required for Win7. Can download WebSocket4Net(0.9).Binaries.zip from http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/downloads/get/830268 and From the downloaded zip file, copy net45\Release\WebSocket4Net.dll into the %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows folder on your computer.

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP. I checked, and that DLL is in the that folder. Any other places I can figure out what is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Go to project

> Properties > Configuration Manager

(left top corner) and check

> deploy

Comment: Deleting the SUO file did NOT solve it for me, but your suggestion did. Thank you!

Comment: Right top corner in VS2015 :) - works for me fine!! Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Close Visual Studio, delete solution .suo files.
Open Solution .sln and test it, this work for me.

Comment: in VS 2015, their hidden in a .vs directory

Comment: Solved it for me in VS 2015 as well

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio go to Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova, select Clear Cordova Cache.

This worked for me to solve the issues above and has been the solution to a few other issues when using these tools.

Answer (score 1):

Need to set Visual Studio F5 action for Build and Deploy for Mobile project from Configuration Manager

1. Right click on the solution and select the **Properties**
2. Select **Configuration Properties** from left panel
3. Select your Mobile Project
4. Set (Tick) **Build** and **Deploy** checkboxes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete Suo file from solution will fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 I had to separately install Ripple as a package of my Apache Cordova Project and restart Visual Studio.  To start Ripple, right click on your project and select deploy.