# Visual Studio for Cordova: unable to get launched browser process for your app

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have been following this guide: [Getting Started With Visual Studio Tools For Apache Cordova](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/build-your-first-app?view=toolsforcordova-2017).

But when I try to run a blank app through the "Simulate in Browser" function, I get this error in the debug output window:

> Unable to get launched browser process for your app.

After that nothing happens.

I've tried several "solutions" to similar problems I found, but none worked:

1. Reinstalling Visual Studio (and the Cordova Tools) [[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907725/need-clarification-on-error-android-development-with-visual-studio)].
2. Deleting the .suo file from the project folder [[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198344/unable-to-get-launched-browser-process-for-ripple)].
3. Modifiying the .sln file from the project folder [[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116752/unable-to-get-ripple-session-info-exception-contentp-body)].
4. Making sure the Deploy checkbox is checked [[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198344/unable-to-get-launched-browser-process-for-ripple)].
5. Cleared the Cordova Cache [[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198344/unable-to-get-launched-browser-process-for-ripple)].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself, turns out all I had to do is grant Visual Studio elevated privileges.